# How to update data elements within a transition without deleting a re-creating everything?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3js v3 have a heat map that upon changing a ratio button selection I would switch the data from one dataset to another. The initialization requires a lot of steps e.g.

```
var svg = d3.select("#myId").append("svg");
...
var heatNode = svg.append("g");
heatNode.selectAll(".cellrect")
   .data(data, function(d) { return d.row + ":" + d.col; })
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.col - 1) * (cellWidth + cellMargin); })
   .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.row - 1) * (cellHeight +  + cellMargin); })
   .attr("class", function(d) { return "cell cell-border cr" + (d.row-1) + " cc" + (d.col-1); })
   .attr("width", cellWidth)
   .attr("height", cellHeight)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); })
   .on("mouseover", function(d) {
       // highlight text
       d3.select(this).classed("cell-hover", true);
       d3.selectAll(id + " .rowLabel").classed("text-highlight", function(r, ri) { return ri == (d.row - 1); });
       d3.selectAll(id + " .colLabel").classed("text-highlight", function(c, ci) { return ci == (d.col - 1); });
            })
   .on("mouseout", function(d) {
       d3.select(this).classed("cell-hover", false);
       d3.selectAll(id + " .rowLabel").classed("text-highlight", false);
       d3.selectAll(id + " .colLabel").classed("text-highlight", false);
   });
```

and now I get new data and would like to update only the `fill` color and nothing else. So I have tried without succcess:

```
   heatNode.selectAll(".cellrect").transition().duration(2000)
       .data(newData, function(d) { return d.row + ":" + d.col; })
       .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });
```

The only way that has worked for me so far is doing an ugly:

```
   heatNode.selectAll("*").transition().duration(2000).remove();
```

and recreating everything again, however, not even then the transition works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems right but you need to add cellrect class to the first selection if you want to use this class to select the elements again

```
heatNode.selectAll(".cellrect")
   .data(data, function(d) { return d.row + ":" + d.col; })
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.col - 1) * (cellWidth + cellMargin);})
   .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.row - 1) * (cellHeight +  + cellMargin); })
   .attr("class", function(d) { return "cellrect cell cell-border cr" + (d.row-1) + " cc" + (d.col-1); })
```

...